# How to Use Awk in a Bash Script [having problems]?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk

So I've been working on an assignment pertaining to awk. Everything is pretty much done, except when I throw commands into a bash script (run eleven of them all automagically) I don't get any output. Am I missing some sort of syntax that awk needs to work in a script? Thanks!

I'll just give you the first four to give you an idea:

```
#!/bin/sh
##VARIABLES
W=/usr/share/dict/words
C=cars_file
P=/etc/passwd


##PROBLEM EXAMPLE
#display problem number
#display command
#run command
#echo whitespace


##PROBLEMS
 echo ">PROBLEM 01"
 echo    "awk '/zzan/ {print}' $W | head"          #contains 'zzan'
          awk '/zzan/ {print}' $W | head           #pipe to head
 echo

 echo ">PROBLEM 02"
 echo    "awk '/^[aeiou].*[ou]rch$/ {print}' $W | head"       #start w/lowercase vowel
 echo     awk '/^[aeiou].*[ou]rch$/ {print}' $W | head        #end in orch/urch
 echo                                                         #pipe to head

 echo ">PROBLEM 03"
 echo    "awk '/chevy/ {print}' $C"                 #display all records
 echo     awk '/chevy/ {print}' $C                  #of all chevys
 echo

 echo ">PROBLEM 04"
 echo    "awk '$1 ~ /o/ {print}' $C"               #display all records
 echo     awk '$1 ~ /o/ {print}' $C                #contains 'o' in column 1
 echo
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first awk entry should work fine (assuming your awk script does what you want. The other three have an erroneous leading `echo` and as such are just echoing the command instead of running it.

Comment: Oh god. I should've seen that. The first one does, indeed, run fine. Thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: @user3010203 don't forget accepting the answer, if it solved your problem.